# Do resonant inductive coupling coils need to be on axis to transmit wireless power?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, oscillators, resonance

I've recently become interested in Nikola Tesla's resonant inductive coupling method of wireless power transfer. I saw an experiment online and the resonant coils seemed to be on axis, or facing each other. I was just wondering if the coils can transmit power when perpendicular to each other.

Answer (score 1):

To maximize the power transfer between two coils you want to maximizes the faction of flux from coil  1 that passes through coil 2 (parallel to the axis of symmetry). The coils might be coaxial or they might be wound on a loop of ferromagnetic material. If one coil were perpendicular (and centered on the other), the flux linkage would be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the coupling (mutual inductance) is maximized if the coils are coaxial.  This is related to the fact that, for a given separation, the field along the axis of a small coil or magnet is twice the field on its equatorial plane. The [dipole-dipole interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction) (which relates to small coils with relatively large separation) gives some insight into how the coupling can vary.  Interestingly, there are positions and angles where the coupling is exactly zero - which is sometimes a useful feature.

For two small coils at right angles, the coupling is maximized when the line joining their centers is at 45 degrees to either coil.